# Why is Pacifico webfont cropped in Webkit browsers?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

I'm experiencing issue with Pacifico font, which is available in Google Fonts. This issue is happening only in Chrome and Safari, other browsers are okay.

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dRcaB/5/

The problem is that the D character is cropped on the left hand side. If I add some `padding-left`, it displays correctly. This is happening only with the Pacifico font.

What's wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pacifico">Deli D</div>
<div class="pacifico padding">Deli D</div>
<div class="damion">Deli D</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Damion);

.pacifico, .damion {
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pacifico {
    font-family: "Pacifico";
    font-size: 60px;
}

.padding {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.damion {
    font-family: "Damion";
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what causes it; probably a bug. But as a workaround, you can give the body a padding-left instead of margin-left. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/dRcaB/7/ Or, if it's only one line, give the element itself a padding-left and a negative text-indent.

Comment: Actually I can't set padding or margin to fix this issue because the value of padding/margins depends on first character in the word. For example different value is needed with character D and character O.

Comment: No, I meant that you can, for example, give the div `padding-left:10px; text-indent:-10px;` so that the first word starts in the same position as if padding and text-indent were both 0. Except it's not cut off any more. Try it.

Comment: Yes this will work - thanks! But it not solving this issue...

Answer (score 0):

i also facing same problem but its browser rendering issue. when you select the character you will understand how browser gives space for the character.

the only patch to solve this issue is use **overflow: visible && padding** property to its parent **DOM ELEMENT.**